# CoreData - Value by ID

Tags: iphone, core-data

Is there any simple way to retrieve property value by ID?

I have used :

```
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

I have retrieved a dictionary of unique values like this:

```
(
    {Category = "0x6d83070 <x-coredata://04C30A5B-A2A2-4342-B5D4-DCE1AAA339DB/Category/p15>";},
    {Category = "0x5cbad20 <x-coredata://04C30A5B-A2A2-4342-B5D4-DCE1AAA339DB/Category/p16>";}
)
```

How to use these ID's?
How to retrieve data from Category-table having these IDs?
Will     objectWithID:objectID help me?

please help

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that should be an instance of `NSManagedObjectID`, which you can give to `-[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:]` to retrieve the actual object.

But this begs the question: why not just fetch everything as an object instead of as a dictionary?  Then you can just do:

```
NSArray * results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
MyManagedObject * obj = [results objectAtIndex:0];
Category * category = [obj category];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use setReturnsDistinctResults:YES - when you use this you have to change type to dictionary. I have tried so many times with object returns all table.

Comment: @Cezar `setReturnsDistinctResults:` requires a dictionary return type? That's news to me! Are you sure that's correct, though? I looked in the documentation and couldn't find anything...